# Can I get values for my protected variables from outside a class?

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to get my variables from a config file.

First I had a class which had this :

```
var $host;
var $username;
var $password;
var $db;
```

Now I have this :

```
protected $host = 'localhost';
protected $username = 'root';
protected $password = '';
protected $db = 'shadowcms';
```

This is used in a __construct function for my mysqli connection

But now I need to insert the values in the class itself instead of getting them from the config file.

Comment: if you want to do that, don't protect them (from doing that in first place)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

protected members cannot be accessed directly from outside the class.

If you need to do so you could provide [accessors](http://cstruter.com/blog/272) to get/set them.  You could also declare them public and access them directly.

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

> Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class
>   itself and by inherited and parent classes.

In other words, in you config class you define the protected properties. They can only be accessed (directly) by inheriting that config class.

```
class ConfigBase
{
  protected $host = 'localhost';
}

class MyConfig 
{
  public function getHost()
  {
    return $this->host;
  }
}

$config = new MyConfig();
echo $config->getHost(); // will show `localhost`
echo $config->host; // will throw a Fatal Error
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a getter with a variable-variable, like

```
public function get($property) {
    return $this->$property;
}
```

Then you can just do

`$classInstance->get('host');`

for example.